# I found a bug in Vercel's Next.js v13.4.4-canary.6 GitHub repo in examples/multi-zones. Can you confirm my findings?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

As I said, in `https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary`, in `next.js/examples/with-zones/blog/pages/index.tsx` there is an error in line 15:

```
<Link href="/">Home</Link>
```

This link is not working and does not direct the user to the `Home` page (which is intended) but to `Blog` page because of `basePath: '/blog'` definition in `next.config.js`.

If you change the line 15 from `Link` to `a`, it works:

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
```

Can you confirm my findings? Does Vercel really have a bug in their multi-zone examples?